# OAuth 2 hash security vulnerability

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

[This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) says when a user finishes an OAuth 2 login, and are redirected to your site with the access code, `#_=_` is appended to the redirect URL.

According to the site:

> The hash fragment is appended to your URL to prevent a security vulnerability.

Can anyone explain this? I can't see how it would affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is done to remove any fragments that might *already* be present in the url, as the behavior during redirects is not specified in any specs.
This is in turn to prevent information passed in the url to an endpoint on Facebook's domain to leak to the page that is redirected to.

Answer (score 1):

Information on a URL presented after the # mark won't be sent to, for instance, proxy servers, and won't be logged on the web server log file.
The reason is that this information won't be sent to the server, however, will be available for the website to access (through JavaScript, for instance).

Comment: Well, while that's true, it still doesn't explain why Facebook do this.